# Return one of two possible classes instances

Tags: swift

I read that it's kind of not recommended to use `Any` or `AnyObject` if possible. My case is, I have a class in charge of communicating with server and returning data into the app, looking like this rough example:

```
class Api {
    init() {
    }

    func login(username: String, password: String) -> User? {
        if (username == "johndoe") {
            let user = User(id: "1234567890", firstName: "John Doe")
            return user
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to return `User` or `Error` object instead of `nil`. Should I replace return class of the `login` function with `AnyObject` so that I could return `User` or `Error` or can I define return type in a more strict way?

Should I rewrite it as

```
func login(username: String, password: String) -> (error: Error, user: User)?
```

Then always check for error to have or not to have a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Swift 2 support for errors like below:

```
class Api {
    init() {
    }

    func login(username: String, password: String) throws -> User {
        if (username == "johndoe") {
            let user = User(id: "1234567890", firstName: "John Doe")
            return user
        } else {
            throw NSError(domain:"MyDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Wrong login"])
        }
    }
}


// do { try ... } catch { ... }
do {
    let user = try Api().login("foo", password: "bar")
    print(user.firstName)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

// Explicit extraction of NSError
do {
    let user = try Api().login("foo", password: "bar")
    print(user.firstName)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.domain)
    print(error.code)
}

// try?
if let user = try? Api().login("foo", password: "bar") {
    print(user.firstName)
} else {
    print("failed login (but lost error)")
}

// try! (crashes on error)
let user = try! Api().login("foo", password: "bar")
print(user.firstName)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with following approach:

```
enum ApiResult{
    case Filed(NSError)
    case Success(User)
}

class Api {
    init() {
    }

    func login(username: String, password: String) -> ApiResult {
        if (username == "johndoe") {
            let user = ApiResult.Success(User(id: "1234567890", firstName: "John Doe"))
            return user
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "Fialed", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
            return ApiResult.Filed(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the return to a tuple. For example:

```
func login(username: String, password: String) -> (user: User?, error: NSError?)
```

So you can return `(user,nil)` or `(nil, error)`

Comment: Just figured out a similar solution a moment ago, thanks anyway!

Comment: `[user: User?, error: NSError?]` ≠ `(user: User?, error: NSError?)`

Comment: Swift has native support for errors with the throw statement, now. This should be the way to go, not an ambiguous type like (User?, NSError?) which can hold two non-nil values, and become meaningless.

Comment: @GwendalRoué Found it out, looks more elegant, would you put it as an answer?

Comment: Ah I made a mistake that tuple syntax is '()'.